# A question about Python script!

Tags: python

```
m = raw_input("Please enter a date(format:mm/dd/yyyy): ")
def main():
    if '01' in m:
        n = m.replace('01','Janauary')
        print n
    elif '02' in m:
        n = m.replace('02','February')
        print n
    elif '03' in m:
        n = m.replace('03','March')
        print n
    elif '04' in m:
        n = m.replace('04','April')
        print n
    elif '05' in m:
        n = m.replace('05','May')
        print n
    elif '06' in m:
        n = m.replace('06','June')
        print n
    elif '07' in m:
        n = m.replace('07','July')
        print n
    elif '08' in m:
        n = m.replace('08','August')
        print n
    elif '09' in m:
        n = m.replace('09','September')
        print n
    elif '10' in m:
        n = m.replace('10','October')
        print n
    elif '11' in m:
        n = m.replace('11','November')
        print n
    elif '12' in m:
        n = m.replace('12','December')
        print n

main()
```

for example, this scrpt can output 01/29/1991 to January/29/1991, but I want it output to January,29,1991  How to do it? how to replace the " / " to " , "?

Comment: You use replace() method over and over in your script, maybe that should give you a good hint...

Comment: I dont know how to make it simple?

Comment: yes, but how to make the different replace() methods work together?

Comment: As a side note, your script is very badly designed; this way of doing it will not work. Try giving it "01/01/2001" as input for a hint.

Comment: I think, should think on other things, not about how to call `replace` twice. Your code will print `"October/29/20October"`. It assigns `n` in each `(el)if` block, and calls `print` there as well... What do you want to do?

Answer (score 11):

Please don't do it this way; it's already wrong, and can't be fixed without a lot of work. Use [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to turn it into a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), and then [`datetime.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to output it in the correct format.

Comment: @user497786: Then learn :) No one can know everything. That is why there are sites like this and documentation to read. Now you learned something new. Be happy, because it saves you a lot of work...

Comment: Ha, I'm not learn that before you tell me, I'm a new one study python.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module:

```
m = raw_input('Please enter a date(format:mm/dd/yyyy)')

# First convert to a datetime object
dt = datetime.strptime(m, '%m/%d/%Y')

# Then print it out how you want it
print dt.strftime('%B,%d,%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you replace all of the other strings - `replace('/',',')`.

Comment: Everywhere. For example `n = m.replace('11','November').replace('/',',')`.

Comment: @user497786 I couldn't really see making a suggestion like that, because this script is in such need of a complete rewrite anyhow...

Comment: He has the best method just above. But for a quick and dirty solution, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a dictionary to be helpful here.  It would be "simpler."  You could try something as follows.

```
m = raw_input("Please enter a date(format:mm/dd/yyyy): ")
month_dict = {"01" : "January", "02" : "February", "03" : "March", ...}
# then when printing you could do the following
date_list = m.split("/") # This gives you a list like ["01", "21", "2010"]
print(month_dict[date_list[0]] + "," + date_list[1] + "," + date_list[2]
```

That will basically get you the same thing in 4 lines of code.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has a good answer.  I don't like mine anymore, but I'm leaving it here because it will get you what you're looking for as well, and could be helpful if someone is looking to do something similar without dates.

Answer (score 0):

I have just rewrite your code more compact:

```
m = '01/15/2001'
d = {'01' : 'Jan', '02' : 'Feb'}

for key, value in d.items():
   if key in m:
       m = m.replace(key, value)
```

Comment: Nice solution, just wanted to type in the same code in my editor until I noticed your answer :-).